# Conditional formatting based on date difference

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

I need help with making the row or at least the cell turn red when it has been >20 days since the date that was entered in the cell. 
For instance: I issue an item to John on 10/01/2018 and so I place that date on my spreadsheet as Date issued, John knows he has to return it in 20 days. So when it's 10/22/2018 how can I make that date cell (10/01/2018) turn red?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the date you enter is in Column B, starting Cell B3. Put the following Formula Rule in conditional formatting screen on B3  and select the cell background color of your choice.

Select B3 go to Conditional Formatting --> New Rule --> Use a Formula to determine which cells to format.

```
   =DAYS(NOW(),B3)>20
```

Use format painter to apply the Format to all applicable cells of the Column B.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Excel 2013, but I imagine it's done the similar way in your version.

To achieve this effect, you need to use **Conditional Formatting**:

- If you want the entire row to get highlighted when the rules apply, select the whole table (without the labels) [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pz2j.png). If you only want parts of the row to get highlighted (like a single cell), select those parts [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6DLe.png).
- Having selected the desired cells, navigate to the **Home** tab of *The Ribbon* (the part above the spreadsheet) and click on **Conditional Formatting** [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azA5p.png) (this is from a Polish version of Excel, but the icon is the same)
- Select **Manage Rules** from the drop-down list [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RjiW.png)
- Click on **New Rule** - we will need to add 3 of them
- In the new window, select **Use a formula to determine which cells to format** from the upper list, then type the following formula in the field: `=$C2-$B2>20` (where B is the column with the issue dates and C with the return dates) [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6tHo.png). *This rule will format all rows where the difference between the two dates is greater than 20 days*
- Select your desired formatting by pressing the **Format** button, then confirm your selection and add the new rule by pressing **OK**. Two more rules to go
- Click on **New Rule**, then select **Use a formula to determine which cells to format** again
- Type in the following formula: `=AND($B2<TODAY()-20;$C2=0)` [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff75I.png). *This rule will format all rows where the issue date is from more than 20 days ago **AND** there is no return date given*
- Again, select the formatting and approve the new rule by clicking **OK**
- Add a **New Rule**, select **Use a formula to determine which cells to format** and type in this formula: `=AND($B2=0;$C2=0)` [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGS9F.png). Do *NOT* change the formatting (leave it on *No format chosen*). *This rule forbids Excel from formatting the empty rows of the table*
- Tick the box **Stop If True** next to the *first* rule on the list (the one you added at the end) [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myfcL.png)
- Accept the three rules by pressing **Apply**, then **OK**

And there you go, Excel:

1. Will format the rows where the difference between the two dates is greater than 20 days
2. Will format the rows where there is only one date and it's from more than 20 days ago
3. Will not format the rows without any dates (the empty ones)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help and I input the formula just as you wrote, the issue is that it now changes every cell in that column red without any data at all. Can you add to the formula to "ignore" cells without dates until a date is entered and then it will follow the formula?

Comment: Of course, my mistake. I fixed it now, hope it works as intended this time

Comment: Sorry one other issue, I am not wanting to know if they are >20 days from today, rather from the date the item was issued. So I enter in column 3: Date issued: 09/01/2018 and Column 4: Returned Date was: 9/8/2018, I don't want that Column to turn red bc it was returned within 20 days. We are trying to only point out if an item issued has not been returned within 20 days of the issue date, does that make sense? Is that possible? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Not a problem, I hope everything will finally be OK now :)